# Using statement in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error, using-statement

I'm having difficultly with the using statement in Visual Basic. Does anyone know how this should be written?:

```
Using (Dim doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, True))
//blah blah
End Using
```

The code works fine without the using and its obviously as syntactic error. "Dim" is highlighted, and an expression is expected apparently. Sorry if this a bit basic, but the info on vb using statements is not clear and its obviously doesn't work in the c# style.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's two things wrong.

First, you must remove the `Dim` keyword.  The `Using` keyword replaces the `Dim` keyword.  Both `Dim` and `Using` have the same effect of declaring a new variable, just in different ways.

Secondly, you must remove parentheses.  The very first thing after the `Using` keyword must be the variable name.

```
Using doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, True)
    ' blah blah
End Using
```